# A good word for waiter or waitress

Tags: contemporary-latin, vocabulary, occupation

What would be a good Latin word for waiter or waitress in a restaurant?
I would not call them *servus*; I find the word inappropriate when not referring to slaves.
*Servitor/servitrix* would be more neutral, but also *minister/ministra* looks suitable.
I also came across [*dapifer*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=dapifer&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (from *daps*+*ferre*), and it became my favorite translation the moment I saw it despite being rare.
Which word(s) would you suggest and why?
Is there a canonical translation?

Comment: See [the meta discussion about tagging translation questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/266/79).

Comment: Ancilla ? for waitress. Was it a dapifer who swopped accounts of dreams with Joseph in prison?

Comment: in Romanian we use _servitor_ in a similar sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a smaller restaurant, [*caupo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D26%3Aentry%3Dcaupo) would be very appropriate, particularly if it's a family business. Another word which was certainly used in Antiquity was simply [*puer*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D124%3Aentry%3Dpuer) (see Sense B.2 in L&S).

But if we were to use a term to describe the job out of context (say, writing it in a *curriculum vitae*, for instance) I'd probably go for *dapifer* as you wrote.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [pincerna](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=pincerna&highlight=pincerna) (Thanks to the comment of @Hugh, I found this word in the Vulgata in the Joseph-in-prison scene.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers here, but the one I like best is in the OP's question, *minister* and *ministra*.

It is true that *minister* has a somewhat broader meaning than "waiter", but if you are in a restaurant setting, I don't think there will be any ambiguity.  I also note that John Traupman's dictionary lists *minister* when you look up "waiter" in the English-to-Latin section.

Answer (score 1):

For a definitively medieval flavour I suggest another word *buticularius* (the source of the modern English word "butler". The word *buticularius* is AFAIK not attested for the Classical period.